# warning /dev/centos/root swap centos-root does not exist -- after configuring DRBD

Tags: centos, lvm, fstab, drbd, dracut

I configured DRBD on default CentOS 7.3 Installation like following:

`/dev/centos/home` was taking all the space in `sda2` so reduced it and created `/dev/centos/home` (20% space) and `/dev/centos/drbd` (remaining space using  `lvcreate -l 100%VG -n drbd centos`)

DRBD resource device is `/dev/drbd0` and disk is `/dev/mapper/centos-drbd` formatted as `ext4`.

Now everytime I reboot the system I get the errors:

```
Warning: /dev/centos/root does not exist
Warning: /dev/centos/swap does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/centos-root does not exist
```

From dracut shell I run :

```
$ lvm vgscan
$ lvm vgchange -ay 
$ exit
```

and system boots fine. But It fails again at `reboot`.

Any solution?

---

UPDATE: Found the cause, drbd device was causing the issue. I removed it from both servers and it fixed the 2nd server but not the 1st one. `blkid` still shows wrong UUID and Type of `/dev/sda2`

```
$ blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="bdfa3672-b24b-41ec-88f8-d0f0a81057d1" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="d8d241f07976f3ce" TYPE="drbd"
/dev/mapper/centos-swap: UUID="3c8653bb-060a-4e46-8eaa-ce51637752ee" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/centos-root: UUID="93941d8b-22e0-4ad7-8666-1ce8ba8d1109" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/centos-home: UUID="63c9a5ad-9b4b-4852-8e95-22b356d8729a" TYPE="xfs"
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you’re seeing this is due of initramfs kernel image being build for the specific system it's running on, so migrating to a new hardware will cause it to fail to boot.

Rebuilding initramfs in emergency mode(or go to the Rescue Mode ):

Then

1. List the initramfs images you have:

   ```
   ls -ltrh /boot/initramfs-*
   ```
2. Locate the kernel version you’re using and create a backup of it:

   ```
   cp -iv /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.img /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.img.back
   ```
3. Rebuild the kernel image for that specific kernel

   ```
   dracut -f
   ```
4. Select the new kernel image

   ```
   ls -ltrh /boot/initramfs-*
   ```
5. Specify the new kernel version (For Example):

   ```
   dracut -f  /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.img 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
   ```
6. Go to the GRUB configuration

   ```
   vim /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
   ```
7. Delete the old menuentry and make sure that the new menuentry is top of all
8. Generate a GRUB configuration file

   ```
   grub2-mkconfig
   ```
9. Reboot
10. Done

Comment: A couple errors but you got me through an IDE-SCSI conversion, thanks! On 3) it should be `dracut -f <kernel img>` otherwise it'll do the booted rescue kernel version. Don't do 6), it tells you in `/boot/grub2/grub.conf` not to edit the file. 8) should be `grub2-mkconfig`

Answer (score 0):

- in Centos edit `/etc/default/grub` as follows:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/cs-swap rd.lvm.lv=cs/root rd.lvm.lv=cs/swap rhgb quiet"
  ```
- change the swap path to the correct path
- run

  ```
  grub2-mkconfig
  ```

  and

  ```
  dracut -f
  ```
- reboot